# How to Set Goal Pose for MoveGroupCommander?

Tags: ros, python, pose, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to set a planning goal for MoveIt! but I keep getting an "Unable to sample any valid states for goal tree" error.  My Python code is shown below.  Anything wrong with this?

```
group = MoveGroupCommander("robot_arm_group")
group.allow_replanning(True)

#set start state
group.set_start_state_to_current_state()

#set goal state
target_pose = PoseStamped()
target_pose.header.frame_id = 'base_link' 
target_pose.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now() 
target_pose.pose.position.x = 1.3 
target_pose.pose.position.y = 0.4
target_pose.pose.position.z = 0.6
target_pose.pose.orientation.x = 0.0 
target_pose.pose.orientation.y = 0.0 
target_pose.pose.orientation.z = 0.0 
target_pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0 

group.set_pose_target(target_pose, end_effector_link="forearm")

group.go()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119421/how-to-set-goal-pose-for-movegroupcommander?/) by [daalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/9331/daalt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2014-01-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [E1000ii](https://answers.ros.org/users/4878/e1000ii/) on 2014-05-13**:
Which tipe of robot are you using? This may be a units issue, x position is 1.3 meters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From your code what i thing its happening is that when you execute go() the pose is not estored. I can not remeber well now. But i thing a i faced this issue in the past. So here is something you can test. you can invoke `group.go(targe_pose)`. That worked for me. And in orther to see if youre specifying invalid poses I recoment you to start the target_pose with `group.get_current_pose()`

And start playing from ther to see if making little modifications to this pose the robot moves.

```
tpose = group.get_current_pose()
print type(tpose)
print tpose
#modify pose
tpose.pose.position.z = z #<put here z> 
tpose.pose.position.x = x #<put here new x>
tpose.pose.position.y = y #<put here new y>
#plan and execute
group.go(tpose,wait = True)
```

If after running the `go` you get the same error it's probable that you are specifying a pose that is not possible due to robots limits (may be orientation or joints limits)

---

Originally posted by [E1000ii](https://answers.ros.org/users/4878/e1000ii/) with karma: 178 on 2014-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PizzaTime](https://answers.ros.org/users/24999/pizzatime/) on 2016-03-28**:
lol this problem took me hours... thank you ! damn documentation

**Comment by [Buldoza](https://answers.ros.org/users/39306/buldoza/) on 2019-02-01**:
This solution saved me ! after trying for somany days. THANK YOU.